# How do I compare a value from a form dropdown and assign values to hidden fields in the form based on that selection?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that I need to populate some hidden fields in the form based upon what a user selects from a dropdown selection in the form. I am trying to use the following if else statement.

```
formObject = document.forms['events_v150810'];
chooseWebinar = formObject.elements["webinarSelection"];
    if ((chooseWebinar.options[chooseWebinar.selectedIndex].value) == "1") {
        formObject.elements["hf_EventID"].value = 'First Webinar';
        formObject.elements["hf_elqCID"].value = '91';
        formObject.elements["hf_elqLPID"].value = '25';
        formObject.elements["hf_elqSLID"].value = '161';        
    }
    else if ((chooseWebinar.options[chooseWebinar.selectedIndex].value) == "2") {
        formObject.elements["hf_EventID"].value = 'Second Webinar';
        formObject.elements["hf_elqCID"].value = '101';
        formObject.elements["hf_elqLPID"].value = '35';
        formObject.elements["hf_elqSLID"].value = '171';

    }
    else {
        formObject.elements["hf_EventID"].value = 'Third Webinar';
        formObject.elements["hf_elqCID"].value = '111';
        formObject.elements["hf_elqLPID"].value = '45';
        formObject.elements["hf_elqSLID"].value = '181';        
    }
```

Even though it is returning the correct value in the console and in the form from the dropdown it always populates the form with the items from the if statement. If I change the dropdown to return a value of "2" I still get the first option. I created a variable and assigned chooseWebinar.options[chooseWebinar.selectedIndex].value to it and recieved a value of 1 even when I had selected an item with a different value. I'm not sure why this would be unless it always assigns the value on the initial page load. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have this code in a change event?

Comment: No I don't I'm reading up on change events right now.

Comment: The change event worked. Thank you for the heads up! Still learning, appreciate the help.

Comment: no problem glad I could help!